# How to stick an UI image to the right edge of text in Unity so the images always sticks on the right side when texts width varying

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, text

How can I achieve in Unity that a UI image always sticks on the right side of the text, even with varying text content? The text and the image are both child of an empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the text child of the image and anchor it to the right.